# AS OLEDB doesn't work over https in Windows 7

Tags: ssas, olap

I think I have very obscure problem. When I try to connect to MS OLAP server from Excel over https it throws me an error "Either a connection cannot be made to the , or Analysis Services is not running on the computer specified". Strange thing is that it doesn't work ONLY in Windows 7. If I use Windows 10, no matter if it's Excel 2013 or 2016 it works (so, msmdmpump.dll and settings are just fine).

Native connection to this server works as well as pure http. Drivers are registered and working just fine (tried with different combinations, with no luck).

Also, servers I was using for testing are in internal domain so trusted by default. I even tried to explicitely add certificate to Trusted Root but no luck.

Any advice, help?

Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Ivan